# Unable to retrieve metadata for X - Creating CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem when trying to create a controller and views for a table in the database called "Announcements", I get the following error message:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/97tt3l.jpg

The following is what I've selected within the add new controller menu:

http://oi59.tinypic.com/536bk0.jpg

And my code looks like the following for the model (GuestModels):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace TheResearchSystem.Models
{
    public class GuestModels
    {
        public class AnnouncementsContext : DbContext
        {
            public AnnouncementsContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection")
            {
            }

            public DbSet<Announcements> Announcements { get; set; }
        }

        [Table("Announcements")]
        public class Announcements
        {
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here, and I'm not sure what the error message means. Anybody know the solution?

Comment: Did you build the solution first ? used to be a problem in earlier versions of VS.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried "Clean Solution" and then "Build Solution", the problem still occurs.

Comment: Try this [link](https://sumitmaitra.wordpress.com/tag/ef/) maybe it helps, looks like a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

As the error states: *"Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, **nested** or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject."*

You are using a nested class. `GuestModels.Announcements`.

You should take the **Annoucements** class out.

Entity Framework mapping do not allow nested classes.

Additionally, you are not providing an **Id** for the Announcements class, this is required for entities to be mapped to a tabled. If you don't want this to have an Id, you can check out [ComplexType](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx) EF attribute.

Comment: @TenMinutesDoe Please mark this as the accepted answer if it helped you. This is a good feedback for others so they know if the answers work.